# I would like to know the difference between a custom list and a survey app

Tags: list

I need to create a survey with some questions, I created it in a survey app, but I can t change format, instead I was informed that in custom list you can have different formats, you can finish with a THANKS page that in the survey app you cant. etc. then the reports I can analyze data in excel.

can you inform?

Answer (score 0):

The Survey App has remained the same from SharePoint 2007. It is question biased and has the ability to allow page breaks for branching logic. I'm working with SharePoint 2013 and it still has the same caned views and limitations that cant be modified at all other than the questions you ask and logic around it flows / works with responses.

A custom list is more a build your own form from scratch sort of App. Its easier to change the columns and views when working with this App.

Once users complete each form list they return to the main default view where they can review the item they submitted. This in a way is its on confirmation as they can see the item they added as it's indicated with the handy "new" indicator or the Created time stamp. Sometimes I make the default view a "My items" like view where it filters the created by items so they only see things they created. (custom list only) The survey returns you to the overview view.